# How do you understand the gerunds in miserando atque eligendo?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, vulgata

Pope Francis's coat of arms has the phrase miserando atque eligendo. My knowledge of Latin grammar has faded, but if I recall correctly, this phrase uses two gerunds.

I think one translation is "by having mercy and by choosing". I like this translation. What I would like to know, though, is what exactly is a gerund, what are the different ways of translating these gerunds, and what are the different ways of translating this motto?

I suspect someone may complain that these topics are easily searchable, but beggars can't be choosers, and we on Latin Stack Exchange are beggars when it comes to questions :) So please forgive me for not searching this on Google.

Comment: Oh, I’m sorry. Feel free to close this question or mark as a duplicate. Thanks for the reference and my apology for not searching the forum first.

Comment: No problem! There's nothing wrong with a duplicate question, and in fact the new version increases the visibility of all the information in the older one.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It also reminded me to accept the answer to the first question—the one that took almost two years to show up!